# When a row is added to one sheet, automatically add a row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

For Example: If I add a row between rows 1 & 2 in Excel sheet 1 then how can I reflect this change automatically in sheet 2?

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

Comment: With vba you would need to add this in a worksheet change event. Are you only wanting to insert a blank row, or a copy of whatever is inserted in the 1st worksheet? I think keeping lists synchronized is best handled with Excel Power Query instead of vba.

Comment: Thank you - I would like to insert/delete a row and copy whatever is inserted on the 1st worksheet.

Comment: Doing this with Excel's power query function would be the best option to avoid formula errors and to handle unforeseen types of changes. It's very easy to do. Are you open to that or must it be vba?

Comment: Thanks Jenn, yes I am open to that. Do you have any tips/documents to use as a starting point?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'll post again soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [VLOOKUP](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) function for that. First column of your Spreadsheet 2 will show first column of Spreadsheet 1 , same for the 2nd column

[image: First Sheet]

This is your first sheet you can change content of A and B column however you want.

For the Second Sheet add following functions

Column A - `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000, Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1000, 1, false), "")`

Column B - `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000, Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1000, 2, false), "")`

Now all changes from Sheet 1 will be shown in Sheet 2 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Edgar -  I am familiar with using VLOOKUP and INDEX + MATCH to add a new row to the end of a data, however, I am still no certain how to add a row in the middle of a data set and mirror this in another worksheet. Do you know how to do this with referencing?

Answer (score 2):

On a worksheet, make a list of your names and convert the list to a table by highlighting the header and the values,  press CTRL+T, give your table a name.  While you still have a cell in the table selected...

[image]

On the ribbon, select Data > Get & Transform > From Table

[image]

The Power Query editor will launch in a new window and you will see the table displayed.  You now have a query table.  Change the name of the query.  When you change the name of the query in the query settings panel on the right, it will update the name of the query in the query navigation panel on the left.

[image]

Add an index column.  Go to Add Column > Index Column > From 1.

[image]

Now you have a dynamic index column attached to the names column.  Go to File > Close and Load To

The query editor window will close and the Load To dialogue box will be displayed.  Select Table > New Worksheet, Load to Data Model > Load.

[image]

Your query table will now be displayed on a new worksheet in your workbook.  You can change the formatting on the Design tab of the ribbon.

[image]

Now, any changes you make to the original table are synced, all you have to do is refresh (Data > Refresh, from the ribbon or by right-clicking on the query table).

Try it out.  Add a new name to the bottom of the data table, then go to the query table, right-click > data > refresh.

Comment: Thank you Jenn - I really appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure! If this helped you please accept the answer and consider upvoting.